# Problems with filtering a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm getting an error message when attempting to filter a nested array in javascript.  The task is to build a function that filters out any sub-arrays of the input array if they contain a specific element in them.

My current code is:

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {

let newArr = [];

  newArr = [...arr];
  console.log(newArr);
  for (var i=0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    newArr.filter(newArr[i] => newArr[i].indexOf(elem) >= 0);
  }
  return newArr;}
```

javascript apparently doesn't like me trying to filter newArr based upon a sub-array newArr[i] because it states that the [] are unexpected tokens.  What's going on here?

Comment: you are assigning newArr[i] within the arrow function to a variable. That's not possible

Comment: Replace the entire function with `return arr.filter(subArr => !subArr.includes(elem))`

Comment: That is not how lambdas work, ```x=>y``` is mostly a short version of ```function(x){return y}```, that is why the brackets make no sense there.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)  you can very easily filter out Arrays that contain a specific element:

```js
const filteredArray = (array, elem) => array.filter(subArray => !subArray.includes(elem));

let testArr = [[1,2,3,4, "a"],[1,2,3,4,8],[1,2,3,4, "a"],[1,2,3,4,5]];

console.log(filteredArray(testArr, "a"));
```